# How to sort references items in aps style?

Tags: bibtex, context

By default in MKIV, apa sorts references by author and year. How can I get the same using aps?

Comment: Member for over two year, 11 questions and no MWE? **−1**

Comment: @HenriMenke MWE? Is this for help or for blaming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sorttype=authoryear`.

```
\startbuffer[references]
@article{Kohn1965,
  title = {Self-Consistent Equations Including Exchange and Correlation Effects},
  author = {Kohn, W. and Sham, L. J.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume = {140},
  issue = {4A},
  pages = {A1133--A1138},
  year = {1965},
}

@article{Hohenberg1964,
  title = {Inhomogeneous Electron Gas},
  author = {Hohenberg, P. and Kohn, W.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume = {136},
  issue = {3B},
  pages = {B864--B871},
  year = {1964},
  month = {Nov},
}

@article{Burke2005,
  author = {Kieron Burke and Jan Werschnik and E. K. U. Gross},
  title = {Time-dependent density functional theory: Past, present, and future},
  journal = {The Journal of Chemical Physics},
  volume = {123},
  number = {6},
  pages = {062206},
  year = {2005},
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[references.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]
\setupbtxrendering[aps][sorttype=authoryear]

\starttext

\cite[Hohenberg1964]
\cite[Kohn1965]
\cite[Burke2005]

\placelistofpublications

\stoptext
```

[image]